# Postgresql - INSERT INTO inside WHILE LOOP Throwing SQL Error [42P01]

Tags: sql, postgresql, while-loop, sql-insert

We have a query that will insert 350 million records into a new table. Instead of inserting them all at once, we put the Insert query in a While Loop. Each iteration will insert about one million records.
We tested the While Loop and the Insert separately and both work. But when we combined the two, the query throws the following error:

SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "test_artist" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at SQL statement

We know the table exists. We've done research on the error but so far we cannot find the answer to fix it.

Below is a simplified version of the query, the While Loop and the Insert combined.
Thank you!

```
do $$
declare 
   counter integer := 0;
begin
   while counter < 5 loop
    insert into test_artist (record_id, name)
    values('2627', 'el tri');
      counter := counter + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;
```

Comment: Table "test_artist" does not exist. Make sure you have the correct table name in the database.

Comment: This error is clean - maybe you use different database, different server or different schema than you think.

Comment: @JishanShaikh We made sure the table name is correct and didn't have any upper case letters or is not surrounded by quotations marks.

Comment: @PavelStehule We're new to PostgreSQL, we try qualifying the name like this: db_name.schema_name.test_artist and still got the error. Are there other ways to do it?

Comment: @CtrlAltElite Then, is the table in the public schema, and you've permissions?

Comment: Why not use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)?

Comment: Thank all for your comments! After running queries to see the permissions and which database was being querying, we figured out that it was connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you! We will explore this option further.